# WSDL2Java for overloaded methods?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am trying to run  WSDL2Java (Apache CXF) on a WSDL that contains overloaded methods (same method name, different parameters). It seems to me like I need to write either a JAX-WS mapping file or a JAXB mapping file to do this, but I feel like I'm being stonewalled by a ton of specifications I haven't read. Anyone have any examples of this ?

Comment: Overloaded methods are not considered WS friendly.  Obviously, the best thing would be for the service provider to offer non-overloaded versions.

Comment: I know, but this ***** API has been considered feature complete for 5 years by the vendor in question, and has a huge installed base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resorted to hand-crafted WSDL in situations like this.  I take the original WSDL and tweak it.